# How can I modify arrows to complement this drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Following the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82901/how-do-i-layer-nodes-boxes-in-a-drawing), I'm now at a point where I have very unsatisfying looking arrows.

If I use the `double` option in the `\draw` command the spacing is too small, and when I increase it, the arrow heads look awful.  As it stands, the arrows look weeny and out of place; I'd like wide arrows (double) with thin arrow heads.

***How can I modify the arrows - preferably in global manner - so that they are in keeping with the drawing?***

And, ***How can modify the arrows so that they are perpendicular to the surfaces they point to?***

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{container}
\pgfsetlayers{container,main}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
\tikzset{
    narrow/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, text width=2cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm},
    small/.style={draw, fill=blue!10, text width=1.2cm, text centered, minimum height=0.625cm, draw=black!60, font=\scriptsize},
    wide/.style={draw, fill=orange!20, text width=8.5cm, text centered, minimum height=1.75cm, rounded corners},
    tall/.style={draw, fill=green!20, text width=1.75cm, text centered, minimum height=8cm, rounded corners},
    squar/.style={draw, fill=yellow!10, text width=5.25cm, text centered, minimum height=3.5cm, rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed}
}

\def\blockdist{5}
\def\edgedist{5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node                 (lib)     [tall]   {Library};
  \node at (3,-1)       (tman)    [narrow] {tmon};
  \node                 (ksman)   [narrow] [right=.75cm of tman]   {ksmon};
  \node                 (stsp)    [narrow] [right=.75cm of ksman]  {stosp};
  \node                 (daemon)  [wide]   [below=.75cm of ksman]  {Daemon};
  \node                 (imgan)   [narrow] [above=1.375cm of tman] {img-analysis};
  \node                 (thrman)  [narrow] [above=.75cm of imgan]  {thermal-analysis};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{container}
     \node              (dio)     [fill=red!10, inner sep=.35cm, fit=(tman)(stsp),  rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed] {};
     \node              (manufac) [fill=red!25, inner sep=.1cm, fit=(ksman)(stsp), rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed] {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \node                 (scrpts)  [squar]  [above=1.5cm of manufac.center] {};

  \node                 (scrr2c2) [small]  [above=0.1cm of scrpts.center] {shell};
  \node                 (scrr1c2) [small]  [above=0.2cm of scrr2c2]       {shell};
  \node                 (scrr3c2) [small]  [below=0.1cm of scrpts.center] {shell};
  \node                 (scrr4c2) [small]  [below=0.2cm of scrr3c2]       {shell};

  \node                     (scrr1c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr1c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr2c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr2c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr3c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr3c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr4c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr4c2] {shell};

  \node                     (scrr1c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr1c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr2c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr2c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr3c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr3c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr4c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr4c2] {shell};

  \draw[<->] (manufac.north) -- (scrpts.south);
  \draw[<->] (imgan.east) -- (scrpts);
  \draw[<->] (thrman.east) -- (scrpts);
  \draw[<->] (thrman.west) -- (lib);
  \draw[<->] (imgan.west) -- (lib);
  \draw[<->] (dio.west) -- (lib);
  \draw[<->] (daemon.west) -- (lib);
  \draw[<->] (daemon.north) -- (dio.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should mention that I'm Latex newb of 2 weeks; this is great stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modifying the arrows and their heads see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/80090#80090) in a [somewhat related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf).

For perpendicular arrows zhe only way I know is to save the proper (x,y) coordinates, and connect the arrows to those.

[image: Perpendicular Arrows]

Declare some new dimensions to save coordinates.

```
\newdimen{\myxdimone}
\newdimen{\myydimone}
\newdimen{\myxdimtwo}
\newdimen{\myydimtwo}
```

Create the paths you need, and get their x,y coordinates with `\pgfgetlastxy{x}{y}`, e.g.

```
\path (thrman.west);
\pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
\path (lib.east);
\pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimtwo}{\myydimtwo};
```

Now create a coordinate based on the saved dimensions and draw the arrow.

```
\coordinate (dummy1) at (\myxdimtwo, \myydimone);
\draw[<->] (thrman.west) -- (dummy1);
```

There may be a simpler solution, but this is what I use in cases like yours.
See the full code below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,fit}
\pgfdeclarelayer{container}
\pgfsetlayers{container,main}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
\tikzset{
    narrow/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, text width=2cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm},
    small/.style={draw, fill=blue!10, text width=1.2cm, text centered, minimum height=0.625cm, draw=black!60, font=\scriptsize},
    wide/.style={draw, fill=orange!20, text width=8.5cm, text centered, minimum height=1.75cm, rounded corners},
    tall/.style={draw, fill=green!20, text width=1.75cm, text centered, minimum height=8cm, rounded corners},
    squar/.style={draw, fill=yellow!10, text width=5.25cm, text centered, minimum height=3.5cm, rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed}
}

\def\blockdist{5}
\def\edgedist{5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \newdimen{\myxdimone}
  \newdimen{\myydimone}
  \newdimen{\myxdimtwo}
  \newdimen{\myydimtwo}

  \node                 (lib)     [tall]   {Library};
  \node at (3,-1)       (tman)    [narrow] {tmon};
  \node                 (ksman)   [narrow] [right=.75cm of tman]   {ksmon};
  \node                 (stsp)    [narrow] [right=.75cm of ksman]  {stosp};
  \node                 (daemon)  [wide]   [below=.75cm of ksman]  {Daemon};
  \node                 (imgan)   [narrow] [above=1.375cm of tman] {img-analysis};
  \node                 (thrman)  [narrow] [above=.75cm of imgan]  {thermal-analysis};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{container}
     \node              (dio)     [fill=red!10, inner sep=.35cm, fit=(tman)(stsp),  rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed] {};
     \node              (manufac) [fill=red!25, inner sep=.1cm, fit=(ksman)(stsp), rounded corners, draw=black!60, dashed] {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \node                 (scrpts)  [squar]  [above=1.5cm of manufac.center] {};

  \node                 (scrr2c2) [small]  [above=0.1cm of scrpts.center] {shell};
  \node                 (scrr1c2) [small]  [above=0.2cm of scrr2c2]       {shell};
  \node                 (scrr3c2) [small]  [below=0.1cm of scrpts.center] {shell};
  \node                 (scrr4c2) [small]  [below=0.2cm of scrr3c2]       {shell};

  \node                     (scrr1c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr1c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr2c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr2c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr3c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr3c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr4c1) [small]  [left=0.2cm of scrr4c2] {shell};

  \node                     (scrr1c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr1c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr2c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr2c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr3c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr3c2] {shell};
  \node                     (scrr4c3) [small]  [right=0.2cm of scrr4c2] {shell};

  \draw[<->] (manufac.north) -- (scrpts.south);

  \path (thrman.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
  \path (lib.east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimtwo}{\myydimtwo};
  \coordinate (dummy1) at (\myxdimtwo, \myydimone);
  \draw[<->] (thrman.west) -- (dummy1);

  \path (imgan.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
  \coordinate (dummy2) at (\myxdimtwo, \myydimone);
  \draw[<->] (imgan.west) -- (dummy2);

  \path (dio.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
  \coordinate (dummy3) at (\myxdimtwo, \myydimone);
  \draw[<->] (dio.west) -- (dummy3);

  \path (daemon.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
  \coordinate (dummy4) at (\myxdimtwo, \myydimone);
  \draw[<->] (daemon.west) -- (dummy4);
  \draw[<->] (daemon.north) -- (dio.south);

  \path (scrpts.west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimone}{\myydimone};
  \path (imgan.east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimtwo}{\myydimtwo};
  \coordinate (dummy5) at (\myxdimone, \myydimtwo);
  \draw[<->] (imgan.east) -- (dummy5);

  \path (thrman.east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myxdimtwo}{\myydimtwo};
  \coordinate (dummy6) at (\myxdimone, \myydimtwo);
  \draw[<->] (thrman.east) -- (dummy6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you read my previous (deleted) comment, sorry: I didn't see it was a stealth-shaped arrow.

Answer (score 4):

When you say

```
\draw[<->] (imgan.east)--(scrpts);
```

your are drawing an arrow from `coordinate imgan.east` to `coordinate scrpts.center` but the arrow will stop at `scrpts` border.

If you want to draw an arrow from `imgan.east` to the intersection point between an horizontal line through `imgan.east` and a vertical line through `scrpts.west` you can use the special syntax

```
\draw[<->] (imgan.east) -- (imgan.east-|scrpts.west);
```

And because `scrpts.west` and `scrpts.center` are on the same horizontal line, you can avoid some typing with `(imgan.east-|scrpts)`.

Changing

```
\draw[<->] (imgan.east) -- (scrpts);
\draw[<->] (thrman.east) -- (scrpts);
\draw[<->] (thrman.west) -- (lib);
\draw[<->] (imgan.west) -- (lib);
\draw[<->] (dio.west) -- (lib);
\draw[<->] (daemon.west) -- (lib);
```

to

```
\draw[<->] (thrman.east) -- (thrman.east-|scrpts.west);
\draw[<->] (thrman.west) -- (lib.east|-thrman);
\draw[<->] (imgan.west) -- (lib.east|-imgan);
\draw[<->] (dio.west) -- (lib.east|-dio);
\draw[<->] (daemon.west) -- (lib.east|-daemon);
```

you will get the desired result.