# How to create the following figures in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to create the following two figures with TikZ

[image]

[image]

I'm tikz beginner, can anybody give me some advice how to do that?

Now i've created the first figure:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes=typetag, row sep=1em, anchor=base},
  mycontainer/.style={draw=black,inner sep=1ex},
  typetag/.style={draw=black, inner sep=1ex, anchor=west},
  title/.style={draw=none, color=black, inner sep=0pt}
  ]
  \matrix[mymatrix] (mx1) {
    |[title]|Text A \\
    Text 1 \\
    Text 2 \\
    Text 3 \\
    Text 4 \\
    Text 5 \\
    Text 6 \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, right=of mx1.north east, matrix anchor=north west] (mx2) {
    |[title]|Text D \\
    Text 13 \\
    Text 14 \\
    Text 15 \\
    Text 16 \\
    Text 17 \\
    Text 18 \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, right=of mx2.north east, matrix anchor=north west] (mx3) {
    |[title]|Text E \\
    Text 19 \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, above=of mx2.north, matrix anchor=south west] (mx4) {
    |[title]|Text C \\
    Text 12 \\
  };
  \matrix[mymatrix, above=of mx2.north, matrix anchor=south east] (mx5) {
    |[title]|Text B \\
    Text 7 \\
    Text 8 \\
    Text 9 \\
    Text 10 \\
    Text 11 \\
  };

  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx1)] (n1) {};
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx2)] (n2) {};
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx3)] (n3) {};
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx4)] (n4) {};
  \node[mycontainer, fit=(mx5)] (n5) {};

  \path[->,thick] (n1) edge (n2);
  \path[->,thick] (n3) edge (n2);
  \path[->,thick] (n4) edge (n2);
  \path[->,thick] (n5) edge (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As already mentioned I'm a TikZ beginner, so there are the following problems:

1. How can the boxes around "Text 1", "Text 2" and so on have the
   same width and height? I'd like to have them centered, too.
2. How can I create the arrows look like in the sample picture? Actually they seem badly arranged.
3. How can I create the black boxes like in the sample picture?
4. Is it the right way to use matrix to create this figure, could it be done easier?

Here is the LaTeX-code for the second figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning-plus}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
kreis/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=20pt},
every node/.style={align=center}]

\matrix(mat)[row sep=10pt, column sep=60pt] at (0,0) {
\node[kreis](k1) {}; &
\node[kreis](k2) {}; &
\node[kreis](k3) {}; &
\node[kreis](k4) {}; &
\node[kreis](k5) {}; &
\node[kreis](k6) {}; \\
};

 \draw[-latex] (k1) -- (k2);
 \draw[-latex] (k2) -- (k3);
 \draw[-latex] (k3) -- (k4);
 \draw[-latex] (k4) -- (k5);
 \draw[-latex] (k5) -- (k6);

\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k1.south) {Text 1};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k2.south) {Text 2};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k3.south) {Text 3};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k4.south) {Text 4};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k5.south) {Text 5};
\node [below,text width=2.5cm,font=\small] at (k6.south) {Text 6};

\node (n1) [above=of k1] {};
\node (n2) [above=of k2] {};
\node (n3) [above=of k3] {};
\node (n4) [above=of k4] {};
\node (n5) [above=of k5] {};
\node (n6) [above=of k6] {};


 \draw[latex-latex] (n1) -- (n2) node[midway,above] {Text 7};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n2) -- (n3) node[midway,above] {Text 8};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n3) -- (n4) node[midway,above] {Text 9};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n4) -- (n5) node[midway,above] {Text 10};
 \draw[latex-latex] (n5) -- (n6) node[midway,above] {Text 11};

\node (m1) [above=of n1] {};
\node (m5) [above=of n5] {};
\node (m6) [above=of n6] {};


 \draw[latex-latex] (m1) -- (m5) node[midway,above] {Text 12};
 \draw[latex-latex] (m5) -- (m6) node[midway,above] {Text 13};

\node (k1) [above=of m1] {};
\node (k6) [above=of m6] {};

 \draw[latex-latex] (k1) -- (k6) node[midway,above] {Text 14};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually I have the following problems with it:

1. The arrows above the circles are to short, how can I adjust them?
2. The text above the arrows is not vertically centered, what can I do here?
3. How can I add vertical lines like in the picture above?

Another Question belongs to posting, how can I quickly generate and present a picture of my code?

Comment: These are not terribly difficult diagrams to create. Perhaps some time with the TikZ tutorials would allow you to make a good beginning attempt and then you could ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will try to create the examples.

Comment: *1.* Easy, see [Dependent node size in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227) and linked question. *2.* Easy, can be solved with coordinate specification shortcuts `|-`/`-|`, see for example [the very last code sample of this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121672). *4.* A matrix is very good for this kind of picture. You don’t even need the `fit` library for the simple matrices as you can use options like `draw` on matrices, too. *3.* Matrices cannot be nested (“yet”), TikZ pictures can be nested (but not very nice). A manual approach, maybe? How important is that for you?

Comment: Post a separate question for a separate figure. That way, you can properly accept an answer to both problems/questions/figures.

Comment: On that note: *1.* Use `coordinate`s instead of `node`s. *3.* Use the `|<` and `>|` arrow combination (see also [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051)). *2.* I don’t understand. Vertically centered? There are all one-liners. Though, I would add `text depth=+0pt` to those nodes. For multi-lined nodes this will need more information and really a separate question. (Possibly related: [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227) and linked, [\[3\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/16595))

Comment: Now I have created a new question for the second figure: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146325/how-to-create-the-following-figures-in-tikz-part-2) This Question has been answered for the first figure.

Comment: @wittmaan It seems that your images are no longer visible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the first problem, **nodes having the same size**, see [Dependent node size in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227) (which solution I am going to use) and the linked questions which comes down to identifying the widest/tallest/deepest element and giving its measurements as options to the nodes (see `text width`, `text height` and `text depth`). I am using the `ext.node-families` library from the linked question/answer.

The second problem, **better connections** between the matrices I am going to use the keys `only horizontal first` and `only vertical first` from the [`ext.paths.ortho` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595) which got developed for another [Antwort von mir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87463/16595).
These are similar to the path operations `-|` and `|-` but don't draw the second part. An optional argument shifts the resulting line orthogonally to its direction.

Your fourth point, regarding the **use of matrices**, I think that this is a good example to use matrices, even though we only have one column per matrix. For more complicated stuff and maybe even the matrices with the bold black border, one can use a combination of the `fit` and the `backgrounds` library. For examples see my answers [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132939/16595) and [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82908/16595).

Now, the **black borders** *will* require work. I am using here a solution that first places the fully filled node (“Longer Text D” and “Text E”), and then adds a matrix directly below it which both are then `fit`ted with a node that is only used for the `draw`n line around it.

There are many different approaches possible for this problem. It is our advantage that these problematic matrices are only placed in the lower row of all matrices and only to the right of other matrices. Note the `xshift` and `yshift` in the `Title` style. If you want to place it to the left, you need to use a negative `yshift` value (well, at least if you want to use the “correct” node distance). If you want to place such matrices above other nodes/matrices, you better first place the matrix part of this structure (then with a positive `yshift` for correction of the black border) and then the `Title` above it (but then without any shifting values).

The `ext.positioning-plus` library adds another set of `…=of …` keys to the `positioning` library (and also loads `fit`). This introduces the `north right=of <ref-node>` key that basically is the same as `right=of <ref-node>.north east, anchor=north west`.

This library also allows us to use `x_node_dist` and `y_node_dist` as a reference to the node distances that is set with the `node distance` key.

---

All mentioned libraries starting with `ext.` are part of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,          % for proper arrows
  matrix,               % for “matrix of nodes”
  ext.positioning-plus, % for “x/y_node_dist”, “north right=of …”
  ext.node-families,    % for “node family/width”
  ext.paths.ortho       % for “only vertical first”
}
\tikzset{
  fitty line width/.initial=.25cm,
  fitty/.style={
    fit=(#1')(#1''),
    line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fitty line width},
    inner sep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fitty line width}/2,
    draw, name=#1},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  my matrix*/.style={
    nodes={inner sep=+1em, typetag, node family/width=m, text depth=+0pt},
    matrix of nodes, row sep=+.5em, node family/width=M},
  my matrix/.style={
    my matrix*, draw, row 1/.append style={nodes=title}},
  title/.style={draw=none, node font=\bfseries},
  Title/.default=-+, % use different signs for different placements
  Title/.style 2 args={
    title, draw, node family/width=M,
    fill, text=white, text depth=+0pt, inner ysep=.5em, outer sep=+0pt,
    yshift=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fitty line width})*#11,
    xshift=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fitty line width})*#21},
  typetag/.style={draw=black, inner sep=1ex, align=center},
  >=Latex
]

  \matrix[my matrix] (mx1) {
    Text A \\
    Text 1 \\
    Text 2 \\
    Text 3 \\
    Text 4 \\
    Text 5 \\
    Text 6 \\
  };
  
  % Title makes sure the extra thick line around everything is taken
  % into account, i.e. the node needs to be shifted a bit more
  \node[Title, north right=of mx1]       (mx2')  {Longer Text D};
  \matrix[my matrix, below=+0pt of mx2'] (mx2'') {
    Text ABC\\
    Text 13 \\
    Text 14 \\
    Text 15 \\
    Text 16 \\
    Text 17 \\
    Text 18 \\
  };
  \node[fitty=mx2]{}; % the thick black box around it

  \node[Title, north right=of mx2]        (mx3')  {Text E};
  \matrix[my matrix*, below=+0pt of mx3'] (mx3'') {Text 19 \\};
  \node[fitty=mx3] {};

  \matrix[my matrix,
    above=of mx2.north,
    matrix anchor=south east, xshift=-.5*x_node_dist] (mx5) {
    Text B  \\
    Text 7  \\
    Text 8  \\
    Text 9  \\
    Text 10 \\
    Text 11 \\
  };
  \matrix[my matrix, north right=of mx5] (mx4) {
    Text C  \\
    Text 12 \\
  };

  \path [thick, ->]
    [only horizontal first=-y_node_dist] 
      (mx1.north east) edge (mx2)
      (mx3.north west) edge (mx2)
    (mx5.south east) edge[only vertical first=-x_node_dist] (mx2)
    (mx4.south west) edge[only vertical first= x_node_dist] (mx2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much, that is, what I was looking for. Sorry for being not fast ennough to say, that the black borders are nice, but not important.

Answer (score 13):

Since you already have the two PDF files (`fig_process` and `fig_steps`), it is very easy:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{fig_process}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{fig_steps}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This is the best answer on "Please, draw it for me" questions I've read so far!

Comment: I will add this to a set of standard answers. :D

Comment: That's a nice answer! I didn't say please draw that for me, i only wanted some idea how to start and which concept of tikz (matrices,...) would be useful for such figures. So having the displayed figures is not helpful for me, since i need them with completely different content for my work.

Comment: @user2143654 My answer (which contained a hint of irony) is now obsolete since you changed your question.

Comment: A deprecated answer can still get voted up.